# Should I mark as a duplicate if the questions are close (not truly duplicate) and the same answer applies?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I saw [add a hover effect over an image (better practices) CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453792/add-a-hover-effect-over-an-image-better-practices-css#43453792) just now and thought to myself "This seems familiar, I'm fairly sure I answered something like this in the past". Sure enough, a couple months ago, I answered [Display an image while hover on a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516712/display-an-image-while-hover-on-a-text).

I would use the same method detailed in my old answer to answer the new one (obviously changing the example a bit to be more relevant), but the questions are not truly duplicate and I can see how someone new to CSS/HTML would be confused if we just presented the old answer with no explanation.

Hence my question. Basically, **should duplicates be determined by sameness of question or answer?**

*Postscript: To prevent an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), is there a different, better, way of handling this then the binary options my question implies?*

Comment: You can flag to close that first question as "too broad" or "primarily opinion based". "Best practices" questions are frequently couched in terms of "what's the best way to do this" which will always be an opinion. This one seems to be asking for any/all ways of doing it, which invites a ton of crappy answers (as are the two already received).

Comment: If it already has an answer in a different question, even if the original question is different, I think that the duplicate flag does apply. If there are multiple answers in the duplicate target and only one of them is pertinent, or a slight clarification would help, you can do that in the comments.

Comment: The term '**exact** duplicate' is misleading and over-reaching. If the base problem is covered by another question (which has been answered adequately with positive feedback)  then the OP of the duplicate should be able to read into the question and answer that their post was marked as a duplicate of. Of course there are really no true **exact** duplicates unless someone copied and pasted one question into a new question; it is the underlying problem that has been asked and answered in another post.

Comment: it depends.... this kind of thing should be decided on a case-by-case basis. for example, i have no problem dupe voting any question that revolves around trying to use an asynchronous function as if it were synchronous of the returning from an asynchronous function cannonical, regardless of whether it's client-side or server-side, uses jquery or doesnt, etc.